# get dynamic sequence length from PaddingFIFOQueue

Tags: tensorflow

I use `tf.PaddingFIFOQueue` or `tf.contrib.data.PaddedBatchDataset` to feed in sequences of varying lengths and `dequeue_many` to get a zero-padded batch out of it.

Is there some generic way to also get the sequence length for this batch?

My current solution is to explicitly provide the sequence length as additional input to the queue, i.e. I have sth like `tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(names=["data", "seq_length"], ...)`. I could also use `tf.ones_like()` but my current way seems cheaper and simpler. But I wonder if that is the canonical/standard way or if there is some other way.

Comment: Can you illustrate your question with some code? Why does `.get_shape()` on the resulting tensor doesn't work in your case?

Comment: @sygi: get_shape will return (batch, max_length, ...), because it is zero-padded. So how do I get the length for each sequence now?

Comment: Can you assume that original sentences don't have trailing 0s?

Comment: @sygi: No. Or even if I can, I am asking specifically for a generic way which works for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your `data` and `seq_length` into a tuple (or a list) and then push the tuple into the queue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
q = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.int32, tf.int32], shapes=[[], [None]])
eq1 = q.enqueue([1, [1]])
eq2 = q.enqueue([2, [2,3]])
eq3 = q.enqueue([3, [4,5,6]])
dq = q.dequeue()
sess.run(eq1)
sess.run(eq2)
sess.run(eq3)
sess.run(dq)  # [1, array([1], dtype=int32)]
sess.run(dq)  # [2, array([2, 3], dtype=int32)]
sess.run(dq)  # [3, array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Note that this is exactly what I describe as my current solution. So basically your answer is that there is no better way as what I already describe.