# How to get the sequence lengths from padded batches from a `tf.data.Dataset`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

E.g. imagine I use the [Librispeech dataset via TFDS](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/librispeech) (or whatever dataset, including sequences of varying length of data), and then use [`padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) to create batches, e.g. like this:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

dataset = tfds.load(name="librispeech", split="train_clean100")
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1024)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(32)
```

Now when iterating through the resulting dataset, i.e. over the (padded) batches, how would I know the original sequence lengths in the padded batch? Or is this information lost at this point? How would I extend the pipeline to include it? Is there a special dataset like `AddSeqLengthInfoDataset` or so? This would need to run **before** the `padded_batch`, right?
(This is basically an equivalent of [my question for TF `PaddingFIFOQueue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675692/get-dynamic-sequence-length-from-paddingfifoqueue) but for `tf.data.Dataset`.)

Is there some example? (I wonder a bit that I have not found anything about this. I would assume this is a pretty standard requirement when you work on sequences, that you need to have the information about the original sequence lengths, or not?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a new field to the dataset holding the size of the sequence, for example like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Make a dataset with variable-size data
def generate_data():
    for i in range(10):
        yield {'id': i, 'data': range(i % 5)}
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_data,
                                    {'id': tf.int32, 'data': tf.int32},
                                    {'id': [], 'data': [None]})
# Add field with size of data
ds = ds.map(lambda item: {**item, 'size': tf.shape(item['data'])[0]})
# Padded batch
ds = ds.padded_batch(3)
# Show dataset
for batch in ds:
    tf.print(batch)
```

Output:

```
{'data': [[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 1]], 'id': [0 1 2], 'size': [0 1 2]}
{'data': [[0 1 2 0]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 0 0 0]], 'id': [3 4 5], 'size': [3 4 0]}
{'data': [[0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 2]], 'id': [6 7 8], 'size': [1 2 3]}
{'data': [[0 1 2 3]], 'id': [9], 'size': [4]}
```

Then you can use for example [`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) with the value of that field to mask the padding values.

Another option is simply to pass some special `padding_values` to [`padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) that cannot appear in the actual data, e.g. `-1` or `nan`, but that depends on whether those are actually invalid values for your problem.

Comment: Ok, this basically would solve it. (It's also the same as for my linked question on queues.) Is is the standard way to do it? (I wonder why none of the docs mention this? Is this really so uncommon?) Also, is this efficient? That `lambda` in `map` is called effectively only once and then it would store the TF computation graph, right? So the `session.run` later would not call this Python function again and again? (Or put differently, I could export the TF computation graph and run this purely in C++ later, right? Given that the `generate_data` would also be some native TF op.)

Comment: @Albert If this gets "graphed", then yes, this should only run once on graph creation, for eager mode I'm not sure, I think it may run every time unless you replace the `lambda` with a [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function). I'm not sure how common or uncommon this is, I think for many cases just using the right `padding_values` is enough (in fact, if you are using a [`Masking`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking) layer in Keras you are expected to have that kind of "invalid" padding value).